# Python (google apps) receive and send HTTP POST

Tags: python, google-app-engine, post

Assume a complete newb here :(
I am trying to do something that should be simple and I can't :(
Send an HTTP POST and receive one and see its data on my localhost.
But I can't do all three together :(
I've tried many iterations of code (been on it 7 hours now), this is my latest:

```
class MainPageGet(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        txt_url_values = urllib.urlencode(senddata)
        txturl = 'http://localhost:9080'
        result = urllib.urlopen(txturl, txt_url_values)
        result.read()

    def post(self):
        self.response.write(self.request.get(txt_url_values['message']))
```

Keep getting:
405 Method Not Allowed

The method GET is not allowed for this resource. 
(Or a blank page)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you upload your app.yaml file?

Comment: Besides your question. You cannot have two post methods in one handler. So what is the purpose of the second post? Use another handler or another method.

Comment: application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: testingtxt.application

libraries:
- name: webapp2m
  version: latest

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do here, but you're getting the `405 Method Not Allowed` error when visiting the page because you haven't declared a `get()` method. If you just open up the URL, you're automatically initiating a `GET` request, not a `POST`. Additionally, you can't have two `post()` methods in the same class.

Are you just trying to initiate a `POST` with the information in `txt_url_values` to the same url? If so, you should just be able to rename your first method to `get`:

```
def get(self):
    txt_url_values = urllib.urlencode(senddata)
    txturl = 'http://localhost:9080'
    result = urllib.urlopen(txturl, txt_url_values)
    result.read()
```

Comment: Hey Nate, sorry for not being clear in my OP, lots of frustration here! hehehe :) some how I had the thing I wanted to do working with two different apps. And since I still don't understand what I am doing, I broke it again :( What I want to do is the following: I have an application that receives a POST with some data, manipulates the data and sends back a POST with the answer. This much I think I have working. Now I am trying to build a tester application (or 2) I  simply need to send a POST and receive a POST. I am using the localhost to see the final data.

Comment: The same handler can send and receive a `POST`, but it can't have two `post` methods, like in your example above. It should be fine to set the first as a `get`, which sends the `POST` request to the same handler. That will then be handled by the `post` method.